# Angular 7 testing - simulate input event with debounce time

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-test

Before starting this question. I'm aware, that there are a lot of similar asked questions liked mine. But no solution was able to help me out.

I created a custom auto-complete with rxjs and want to test if a method gets called on a input event. But the error says the method never got called, like:

```
 Expected spy CityService.getLocation to have been called with [ 'mun' ] but it was never called.
```

#### html

I subscribe to my observable in the HTML via the `async` pipe.

```html
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="location" class="form-control" id="locationSearchInput"/>
      <div class="spacer">
        <p class="invalid-feedBack" *ngIf="searchFailed && location.length > 0">Nothing found.</p>
        <ul id="search" *ngFor="let item of (search | async)">
          <li class="resultItem" type="radio" (click)="location = item">{{item}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

#### component

```js
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.search = fromEvent(document.getElementById('locationSearchInput'), 'input').pipe(
          debounceTime(750),
          distinctUntilChanged(),
          map((eventObj: Event) => (<HTMLInputElement>eventObj.target).value),
          switchMap((term: string) => this.cityService.getLocation(term)) <== should get called
        );
      }
```

#### test

```js
      const cityServiceStub: CityService = jasmine.createSpyObj('CityService', ['getLocation']);
      ...
      it('should search for location on init', async(() => {
        const spy = (<jasmine.Spy>cityServiceStub.getLocation).and.returnValue(['Munich', 'Münster']);

        fixture.detectChanges();

        const rendered: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#locationSearchInput'));

        rendered.nativeElement.value = 'mun';
        rendered.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

        fixture.detectChanges();

        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
          console.log(rendered.nativeElement.value);
          expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('mun');
        });
      }));
```

I've also tried to use `fakeAsync` with `tick(750)`. But nothing helped. The `console.log` within the test also shows an empty string as input value. So maybe I'm simulating a wrong Event.

Comment: Testing against Internet Explorer / Edge?

Comment: In my karma.conf.js i use chrome

Comment: Did you try to set `location` to the value `'mun'`? I wonder if in the detect changes process Angular is setting the value to an empty string because the `location` variable is an empty string. Since you have the `distinctUntilChanged()` in your pipe, it wouldn't have then changed since it started as an empty string and then was again after the debounce time. Have you tried to put a log statement at the beginning of your pipe to see what events are firing (if any)? i.e. `tap(e => console.log(e)),` before the `debounceTime(750),`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My test worked with following configuration:

```
  it('should search for location on init', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spy = (<jasmine.Spy>cityServiceStub.getLocation).and.returnValue(of(['Munich', 'Münster']));

    fixture.detectChanges();

    const rendered: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#locationSearchInput'));

    rendered.nativeElement.value = 'mun';
    rendered.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

    tick(750);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('mun');
  }));
```

I missed just to return `['Munich', 'Münster']` as an Observable with the `of()` operator. And I should have used `tick(750)` to wait the specific amount of debounce time for an event change.

Answer (score 0):

Does this code work outside of the test? You haven't posted the whole component, but in the snippets you did post I cannot see a subscription being made anywhere. An Observable won't start emitting until it has at least one subscription (see [here](https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing)).

I implemented your test in my side project and it started working only after subscribing to the Observable, like so:

```
fromEvent(document.getElementById('locationSearchInput'), 'input').pipe(
  debounceTime(750),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  map((eventObj: Event) => (<HTMLInputElement>eventObj.target).value),
  switchMap((term: string) => this.cityService.getLocation(term))
).subscribe()
```

Comment: Ure absolutely right. I subscribe to that observable in the html (Angular stuff)^^. I should have posted more markup to clarify this. Will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: That makes sense, my test is still working though, so the event should be fine. Can you post the whole test setup?

Answer (score 0):

You should call `.subscribe()` for `Observable`. And you should return an `Observable` inside `switchMap`, so, you can't return an array with the spy, but Observable: `const spy = (cityServiceStub.getLocation as jasmine.Spy).and.returnValue(of(['Munich', 'Münster']));`

Comment: getLocation returns an observable... I setup wrongly the spy it should return `of(['Munich', 'Münster'])`. Maybe this is a mistake by me. I will test it today if it helps to solve my problem.